# How can I make a new Admin menu item that is actually displayed in the left hand side menu (System -> Configuration)

Tags: adminhtml, menu, adminmenu

I want to make a menu item, and maybe even a section in admin. This item will link me to a new form in admin. How can I do that, with a new module? I know I need a new module, but what else do I need, what kind of setup of config.xml etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `system.xml` in the `etc` folder of your module. Magento will automatically pick it up when it loads.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <myextension translate="label" module="catalog">
            <label>My Extension</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </myextension>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <myextension translate="label" module="catalog">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>My Extension</label>
            <tab>myextension</tab>
            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <mysection translate="label">
                    <label>My Section</label>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        ...
                    </fields>
                </mysection>
            </groups>
        </myextension>
    </sections>
</config>
```

You can have a look at  the `Magento Core` ones to get some example. Also, note that you will need to add the relevant nodes to your `adminhtml.xml` for permission issues (and you will probably need to log out and log back in to get rid of a persisting permission bug with Magento)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer actually helped me a lot. Although there are other things that need to be in order too. But, following your answer, I found the solution, so, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped :)